# How to find where the CSS height is coming from?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fix the CSS in this classic asp spaghetti code page. The problem is that this particular div container gets a vertical scroll bar. Now my understanding is that unless you set a height, the div tag will expand to contain all the content and will not show a scroll bar. When I look at the div tag in chrome f12 tools, neither do I see a height being set in the CSS nor do I see it being set in the inline style.

Is there any tool or anything I could use to see where this height (if any) is being set.

I am not pasting the code because the rendered HTML is probably over a few pages long.

**UPDATE: i managed to strip out all the unnecessary part and narrow down to the problem code.**

What I want to know is why is the node

```
      <div class="tabData" id="tab3data" style="visibility: visible;">
```

not expanding to fit the contents. Where its height being limited?

```
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        .tabData
        {
            width: 100%;
            background-color: Yellow;
            overflow: auto;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="tabData">
        <div style="height: 390px; background-color: Green;">
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

        </div>
        Hello
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```